# MoveIt! endeffectors and groups

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like the way MoveIt! uses planning groups has changed a bit from the last time I tried it. Now, to be able to specify a goal pose using interactive markers, the arm planning group has to be split up into a arm part (for which the kinematics solver is set) and a endeffector part (see for example [the PR2 tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start)). This works well if the arm used has a dedicated endeffector link rigidly attached to the last link of the arm. But what should be done if that is not the case? I suppose one could add "fake endeffector link" to the URDF, but that seems a bit cumbersome and unnecessarily complicated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58992/moveit!-endeffectors-and-groups/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Agreed.  I believe the "end-effector" group is used for some grasp-planning activities, and to display a "pretty" model at the desired end-effector location when using the planning tool, benchmarking tool, etc.

I talked some with Ioan (one of the primary moveIt developers) about this, and I think he's already implemented a cleaner solution for robots without a true "end-effector".  It looks as if [some](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/commit/d3275858f10e945969104f1554f789e31f51dbc1) [fixes](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/commit/7d74f2dd5b61c2c6a0748e9fd056690f2099a25d) were implemented on March 18th, so you might keep an eye out for when these fixes are pushed out to the main debian-package repositories.

For now, the best solution is to create a "dummy" end-effector link in the robot's URDF:

```
<link name="dummy_eef"/>
<joint name="joint_6-eef" type="fixed">
  <parent link="link_6"/>
  <child link="dummy_eef"/>
</joint>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4